# SharePoint 2019 create library view file name based on user ID

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-addin, 2019

I have SharePoint 2019, I am planning to configure employee's pay-slip over SharePoint. What I am getting from Finance is the pay-slip pdf file for each user, and each file has an employee ID as a file name. I have created a Document Library to upload all these files, but how do let each employee see only his own pay-slip file. in AD each user has an EmployeeID attribute.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, we may not be able to achieve your needs. Because although there is no explicit mention of the limit on the number of Views that can be created. According to my test, when the number of my views exceeds 30, an error will be reported.